# Troubleshooting Windows Event Viewer USB error 0x26 status 0xc000038e

Tags: usb, driver, windbg, usb-drive, etw

I need some guidance in how to troubleshoot a low level issue I am facing with some USB devices.

**Background**: I have a `.NET Windows Service` that, scans `connected USB devices via WMI queries` + reads [low level USB data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-layout) using `external C code`.

Although happening seldomly, once in a while a USB device (keyboard, mouse or smart card reader) stops functioning.
Looking at Windows's `Device Manager`, the device shows with a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark.
Looking at `Event Viewer`'s `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel PnP`, I see the following error (for [mouse](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/03F0/device/094A), in this case)

[image]

**XML View:**

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP" Guid="{9c205a39-1250-487d-abd7-e831c6290539}" /> 
  <EventID>411</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-12-22T08:15:21.1540378Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>300</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="3780" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP/Configuration</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyComputerName</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="DeviceInstanceId">USB\VID_03F0&PID_094A\6&1ab5e341&0&2</Data> 
  <Data Name="DriverName">input.inf</Data> 
  <Data Name="ClassGuid">{745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}</Data> 
  <Data Name="ServiceName">HidUsb</Data> 
  <Data Name="LowerFilters" /> 
  <Data Name="UpperFilters" /> 
  <Data Name="Problem">0x26</Data> 
  <Data Name="Status">0xc000038e</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**How does one proceed from here?**

There is no clear indication that the error is caused by the interactions with my .NET Service.
In any case, I guess I need to figure out how are such messages written to Windows' [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/event-tracing-portal). From there, try to locate where in the C code there is a hook or piece of code that feeds the given ETW listener.

1. Is this the right track? Are there shorter alternatives? Am I missing anything else?
2. Could not find conclusive info on what does the `0x26` error/`0xc000038e` status codes mean. Is  there a specific resource for that?
3. Is there a way I can dump data from such error instances into a tool like [Windows Debugger](http://www.windbg.org/) so it loads the the state of all the parts involved - and perhaps help ?
4. Identify the installed driver for this specific device - and search for logs it eventually writes?

Comment: 0:000> !error 0xc000038e
Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000038e (3221226382) - The driver could not be loaded because a previous version of the driver is still in memory.
try verifying your load unload paths maybe

Answer (score 1):

as i commented the error seems to be propagated from
`IopLoadDriver / IopUnloadDriver` Paths Especially @
`nt!PipCallDriverAddDeviceQueryRoutine`

if you can setup a kd connection Set a bp on these routines and get a stacktrace
to analyze it better

```
0: kd> # c000038e fffff807`33000000 L?(fffff807`34046000-fffff807`33000000)
```

returns

```
nt!IopLoadUnloadDriver+0x60:
fffff807`33777b30 81fb8e0300c0    cmp     ebx,0C000038Eh
nt!IopLoadDriver+0xec759:
fffff807`3381d661 41be8e0300c0    mov     r14d,0C000038Eh
nt!PipCallDriverAddDeviceQueryRoutine+0xeb73b:
fffff807`3381e2f3 41b88e0300c0    mov     r8d,0C000038Eh
```

a cursory glance in ghidra shows 26 being assigned to a variable

```
  uVar11 = 0xc000038e;
  if (iVar7 == 0xc000038e) {
    uVar16 = 0x26;
```

or in disassembly

```
   14081e2f3 41 b8 8e        MOV        param_3,0xc000038e
             03 00 c0
   14081e2f9 41 3b d8        CMP        iVar7,param_3
   14081e2fc 74 b9           JZ         LAB_14081e2b7
```

which jumps to

```
14081e2b7 ba 26 00 00 00         MOV        param_2,0x26
14081e2bc e8 13 1d f2 ff         CALL       PipSetDevNodeProblem
```

A DeviceNodeproblem will normally be reflected in an yellow bang or eventlog being written

so you should probably check where your code might try to prevent unloading , loading or keep a handle open

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming to help! Will (try to) check that out.